# c# get windows users profile details?

Tags: c#, windows, profile

I'm trying to get a detailed list (containing name, size, and last modified) of all user profile on a local machine. I can find the information by going to Computer->Properties->Advanced->(user profiles)Settings and i'm trying to find a way to pull in that information into my c# program. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. In Visual Studio 2008 go to View->Server Explorer.
2. Then drill down to Servers->[YOUR LOCAL MACHINE]->Desktop Settings
3. Create new project (e.g. console application)
4. (Back to Server Explorer) Right click on Desktop Settings node and click on Generate Managed Class menu item.
   After that a reference to System.Management.dll and new class derived from System.ComponentModel.Component will be added to your project. You can inspect it or use it as is.

Also check [WMI Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394554(VS.85).aspx) and [System.Management Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) to study about management information and events.